# How Can I Drop Gun?

Tags: rimworld

Is it possible to drop the gun, and maybe move it to the trash?
I have plenty of unecessary weapons. I want to get rid of them.

Comment: I find they trade well, and I think there's a late-game construction that will let you melt them down for metal, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way to remove unwanted weapons is to trade them away. Set a stockpile to store only weapons and build a trade beacon nearby. You will also need the capacity to trade to be set up. When you get a notification that a trader is passing by, send a colonist to interact with the communication device to initiate trade. You can then sell the weapons for silver or for other useful items.

Answer (score 1):

To actually drop a wielded gun you select your character, go to gear tab and you will have `info` and `drop` actions in the context menu of the gun.
(Alpha 8d)

Answer (score 0):

If they are not worth trading (poor quality) you can smelt them.

https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Electric_smelter